# Event listener only works once

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

I'm creating this function inside an Event listener to add/remove some classes to my HTML on click. The problem is the Event listener only working for one time and it require to refresh the page to work again. I also tried to use onClick and it doesn't work.

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const menuNav = document.querySelector('.menu-nav');
const menuBranding = document.querySelector('.menu-branding');
const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item');

let showMenu = false;

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);

function toggleMenu() {
  'use strict';
  if (!showMenu) {
    menuBtn.classList.add('close');
    menu.classList.add('show');
    menuNav.classList.add('show');
    menuBranding.classList.add('show');
    navItems.forEach(item => item.classList.add('show'));

    // Set Menu State

    showMenu = true;

  } else {
    menuBtn.classList.remove('close');
    menu.classList.remove('show');
    menuNav.classList.remove('show');
    menuBranding.classList.remove('show');
    navItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('show'));
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="menu-btn">
    <div class="btn-line"></div>
    <div class="btn-line"></div>
    <div class="btn-line"></div>
  </div>

  <nav class="menu">
    <div class="menu-branding">
      <div class="portrait"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="/" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="/about.html" class="nav-link">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="/work.html" class="nav-link">My Work</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="/contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact me</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why it should only work once. But there's nothing in the `.menu-btn` div to click on. Also, there's no CSS associated with the classes, so we can't see what the result should be,

Comment: Can you add all the missing pieces to the snippet so we can try it?

Comment: .menu-btn is a Hamburger menu and inside this div nested div's with some width and height and background color to shape the menu icon.

Comment: Codepen link https://codepen.io/AlaaSaedy/pen/ewaBZd

Comment: Please add the code to the stack snippet here, instead of codepen.

Comment: You're missing `showMenu = false;` in the `else` block.

Comment: do i need to remove it and put it in ``else `` block or just repeat it inside the block ? i tried both and no updates

Comment: You need it in both. It needs to toggle every time you click.

Comment: Codepen: https://codepen.io/barmar/pen/PrvbWg

Comment: Now it's working fine. Thanks @Barmar for you help

Comment: It works in my pen, I don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Sorry i didn't notice your pen and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to toggle `showMenu` back to `false` when you close the menu.

```
function toggleMenu() {
  'use strict';
  if (!showMenu) {
    menuBtn.classList.add('close');
    menu.classList.add('show');
    menuNav.classList.add('show');
    menuBranding.classList.add('show');
    navItems.forEach(item => item.classList.add('show'));

    // Set Menu State

    showMenu = true;

  } else {
    menuBtn.classList.remove('close');
    menu.classList.remove('show');
    menuNav.classList.remove('show');
    menuBranding.classList.remove('show');
    navItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('show'));

    showMenu = false;
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/barmar/pen/PrvbWg)